# Как получить правильный ввод value поля input из формы в PHP?

Tags: php

Используя следующий код:

```
<form action="php/authorization_php/signup.php" method="POST">
                    <strong>Your login</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>"/><br/>
</form>
```

я получаю вот такой вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какое расширение у файла, в котором вы это пишите?

Comment: Пробовал .html и .php - результат одинаковый

Comment: это ваш единственный пхп код? пхп вообще работает на сервере?

Comment: Кода, конечно, поболее будет. Это пример того, откуда начинается проблема. Используется redbeen для добавления введенных данных в базу данных, но я считаю это лишнее т.к. это уже дальше. Мне кажется, что дело в синтаксисе. Когда использовал phpStorm, то он говорит, что @$data['login'] является непроинициализированной переменной.

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать. Проблема была в пути к файлам.